# How can I restrict the use of operations in Azure API Management (APIM) per group

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I'll be so gratefull if you can help me with the following question: I´m resticting the access to use an API in APIM using groups, but I want to restrict even its operations for example: I have an API in APIM with the following operations:

- OperationA
- OperationB
- OperationC

And the following groups of users:

- Group1
- Group2
- Group3

so the idea is to give access to the groups according some business rules for instance:

- Group1 (OperationA, OperationB)
- Group2 (OperationA)
- Group2 (OperationA,OperationB,OperationC).

Is there a way to implement this behavior? Thank you so much

Comment: This is a typical authorization problem. Please check Authorization with Spring Security(Assuming you are using SpringBoot).

Comment: @TusharBanne No its about Azure API Management policies only.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us your code, or at least name the programming language that you use.

Comment: @StimpsonCat Its all about Azure API Management policies nothing related to programming language. otherwise I am working with .net core (c#)

Comment: This is a classic example of using RBAC. Role based access control. This should be possible in Azure. You create roles (OP1, OP2, OP3) and assign it to the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you can use [validate-jwt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT) policy at the operation level.

First, you need to include `groups` claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes). You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the user belongs to like below:

```
{
  "groups": ["1ce9c55a-9826-4e32-871c-a8488144bb32"]
}
```

Then use validate-jwt policy in your APIM to check if the field `groups` contains the group(group1, group2 or group3) id. If yes, then do the backend api. If no, you can set a 403 forbidden response in policy like below:

```
<return-response>
    <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
</return-response>
```

Comment: almost you are correct that I need. But I need to know the apim code for that. I have group claims into jwt token already. Only I need to check if operation has permission for that group or not.